# How should fix createContext error in Typescript (React TS Auth with Contexts)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-context, createcontext

How should I fix the problem with createContext? It expects some arguments, but I can't see what arguments. I tried giving it some dummy currentUser: undefined variables and it kinda works, but I can't figure out what should I do with other defaultValues like login, signup etc. It's based on JS Auth tutorial, and in JS it works, but I would like it to work on TSX. Thanks in advance, code below

AuthContext.tsx

```
const AuthContext = createContext()

export function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export default function AuthProvider( {children}:any ) {

    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();

    function signup(email: string, password: string) {
        return supabase.auth.signUp({
            email: email,
            password: password,
        })
    }

    function login(email: string, password: string) {
      return supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
        email: email,
        password: password,
    })
    }

    function logout() {
      return supabase.auth.signOut()
    }

    function recoverPassword(email: string) {
      return supabase.auth.resetPasswordForEmail(email);
    }

    function update(data: any) {
      return supabase.auth.updateUser(data)
    }

    const value = {
        currentUser, login, signup, logout, recoverPassword, update
    }
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an interface that describes the data you want to store in the context:

```
interface AuthContextType {
    currentUser: IUser;
    login: (email: string, password: string) => ......,
    signup: (email: string, password: string) => ....,
    logout: () => void,
    recoverPassword: (email: string) => ....,
    update: (data: any) => ....
}
```

Create an object that describes the initial state:

```
const initialState = {
    currentUser: null,
    login: (email: string, ....) => console.error('No AuthProvider supplied. Wrap this component with a AuthProvider to use this functionality.'),
    ...
};
```

Then create the context:

```
const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>(initialState);
```

Comment: Okay, almost works
Now I call this function (let's say "login") in some component and it is called as
`const { error, data } = await login(email, password)` which gives me an error that "TS2339: Property 'error' does not exist on type 'void'." => What should I change in order to manage errors in this component?

Comment: That error indicates the the value that's being returned by `login` does not include an `error` property.
You can check the value returned by `login` first by logging it:
`console.log(await login(email, password))`

Comment: how to describe an promise function in initialState? for example login function will return a promise of <string>

Comment: @Manspof Something like 
`login: (email: string, password: string) => Promise.reject('My custom error message')`

Answer (score -1):

You can either type `createContext` with `YourInterface | null` as in

```js
const AuthContext = createContext<YourInterface|null>(null);
```

or type cast an empty object as in

```js
const AuthContext = createContext({} as YourInterface)
```